# How to draw Ven Diagram through core-plot or core graphics?

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-graphics, core-plot

Anybody knows how to draw Ven-Diagram. Please give some ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think core plot can help you in this as it is basically configured to draw graphs. For this I think you will have to come up with something of your own may core graphics can help.